# my scrollView doesn't scroll when i put a button in it

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a simple `UIScrollView`. I initialise it this way :

```
self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(500, 200);
//[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,770)];
[self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

But when I put a button in it, it wont scroll anymore!

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: Please add the code where you add the button. Also, is your content size smaller than the size of the frame?

Comment: there is no code for the button, is dragged it in the view...

Comment: and the content size is bigger than the frame

Comment: How big is the button? Are you trying to drag the scrollView by starting on the button? Your button is going to intercept your touch events.

Comment: no the button is small. And the scrollView doesn't work either if i put a label instead of a button..

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is make the `(500, 200);` into something bigger than the dimensions of the screen. `(500, 200);` means the scroll view is 500 x 200 pixels which is smaller than an iPhones screen dimensions. you need to increase those numbers beyond the screen sise of the device you're testing on.

use [this link](http://www.iphoneresolution.com/) for screen sizing guidelines.